# can't build yeoman angular app

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular, grunt-cli

I have a problem with building an angular js web app generated with yeoman angular generator. I can run the `grunt serve`, and it's completely fine. But when I tried to build the app using `grunt`, I got the following errors.

```
Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task
Warning: Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Warning: Error: spawn ENOENT in file app/images/yeoman.png Use --force to continue.
```

The thing is I can build that app (exactly the same app, just copy and paste) on other latop, using same OS, same npm version, same grunt version.

I'm using:

```
mac osx    - v10.9.5
npm        - v2.0.2
grunt-cli  - v0.1.13
grunt      - v0.4.5
yeoman     - v1.2.1
```

Please, help me how to fix that error. thanks

Comment: seems like yeoman.png is in use or for some reason it's blocking your build, try to delete the image and see how it goes

Answer (score 2):

You have to update imagemin. (You may edit imagemin version at your package.json).

I observed the same issue with imagemin 0.8.2. Imagemin 0.9.2 works fine for me.
Imagemin 0.9.2 require npm version >=2.1.5, you have to update npm too(npm install -g npm).